# SSLException - Hostname in certificate didn't match

Tags: java, android, ssl, post, get

I get this exception

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <domain.com> != <*.hostgator.com> OR <*.hostgator.com> OR <hostgator.com>
```

when I use this JSON Parser:

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List<NameValuePair> params) {

        try {

            if(method == "POST"){
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "utf-8"));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, Charset.forName("utf-8")), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }

        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

On some devices it's working normally like on Galaxy S6 running Android 6.0.1, but on most other devices I get error.
Why some devices have problems with it and others don't?

Comment: which other devices, with which android version?

Comment: did you try it with a different host/url?

Comment: One of other devices is Xperia S running Android 4.1.2. I tried different url on the same domain and I still get error. Certificate issuer is COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA.

Comment: what about a completely different domain? try: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

Comment: Could you check your server with  https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html Sometimes COMODO RSA is bad configured on server because it is issued by AddTrust and the chain is not well configured (see common issues at Comodo web)

Comment: Check also the CN of the certificate. For examplo a wildcard certificate `*.domain.com` does not apply to `https://domain.com`

Comment: @pedrofb what exactly should I look for on ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html, there is a lot of information there? Also, how to check the CN of the certificate?

Comment: Search for issues with the certificate or the certification chain. Or post and image with the most representative and I will take a look. CN = Common Name

Comment: @pedrofb Only issue is that server is vulnerable to the OpenSSL Padding Oracle vulnerability (CVE-2016-2107). Also it says that site works only in browsers with SNI support. Everything should be fine with CN since everything is working normally on Galaxy S6 for example.

Comment: @progressive_overload jsonplaceholder.typicode.com doesn't have ssl so I can't check if my code works. If I use http instead of https on my website everything works normally, but I need https.

Comment: ok, then maybe search for a different service first which offers SSL, just for testing and reproducing. I think that would narrow the problem down.

Comment: A `hostname` usually means bad certificate, but if servert tests are okay and it works in some devices, I suggest debugging  javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier to see why is failing, and the differences with the other device

Comment: hi did you get any solution i am having a similar problem [this is the link to my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43090874/hostname-does-not-match-in-lolipop-devices-but-works-fine-in-postman-and-marshma/43091328#43091328)  can you help over there? @pedrofb