# Hostname does not match in Lollipop devices but works fine in Postman and marshmallow devices

Tags: java, android, ssl, httpclient, android-5.0-lollipop

Recently SSL certificates were added to the server, so I have changed the url in android from http://appname.com to https://www.appname.com , this works fine on marshmallow devices and Postman, but on Lollipop devices throws javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: www.appname.com != www.companyname.com OR www.companyname.com OR companyname.com

I have tried adding the companyname.com in setHostnameVerifier but it did not help. here is the code:

```
 HashMap<String, String> postDataParams=new HashMap<>();
        postDataParams.put("u_phone",CN);
        postDataParams.put("u_code",st);
        postDataParams.put("device_flag",mob_device);
        postDataParams.put("app_type","PRO");
        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                HostnameVerifier hv =
                        HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
                return hv.verify("companyname.com", session);
            }
        };


        try{

            URL url = new URL("https://www.appname.com/sync/validatecheck.php");
            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection =
                    (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            //urlConnection.setHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode=urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                String line;
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                    result+=line;
                }
            }
            else {
                result="";

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }
```

What might be the issue here? and how to solve this?

Comment: Which is the hostname to which the certificate has been issued? Check CN field in subject. It should be issued to  www.appname.com or *.appname.com.

Comment: @pedrofb the CN is just appname.com without www or *   , can i edit the same certificate?

Comment: Then the error is correct. You can use `https://appname.com`   but not `https://www.appname.com`. Deploy your server in `https://appname.com`, issue a new certificate for `www.appname.com` or set a HostnameVerifier to allow www.appname.com

Comment: Yes , this works , i did not change anything in the certificate , did not add verifier too , just used https://appname.com .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that the hostname to which the certificate has been issued (CN field in subject) does not match with the server name.

If you are using the URL `https://www.appname.com` then the certificate should be issued to `www.appname.com` or `*.appname.com`. It hostname of the certificate is `appname.com` then error is correct and you can use `https://appname.com` but not `https://www.appname.com.`

Deploy your server in `https://appname.com`, issue a new certificate for `www.appname.com` or set a `HostnameVerifier` to allow `www.appname.com`